# Error while saving All Slides in a PowerPoint file To Sharepoint As Images from PowerPoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powerpoint

I'm seeing a "An error occurred while PowerPoint was saving this file" error while trying to do the following.

Workflow in PowerPoint 2013

1. Go to File > Save As > Sharepoint > Browse
2. Go to desired SharePoint location
3. Change Save as Type to: an Image type: GIF, JPG, PNG, TIFF
4. Click Save
5. Export Every Slide

Exporting only single slide to SharepPoint works just fine. Saving every slide of the file as an image locally also works just fine. The error is seen only when trying to export every slide as image to SharePoint. The SharePoint is the 2010 version.

This is something which I have successfully done in PowerPoint 2010. I have currently used the workaround of saving as png (every slide) locally and then uploading the local folder to SharePoint, but I'm keen solve this issue and be able to save the whole folder at one go.

And any help on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen also on SharePoint 2013 and the problem is that, when exporting all the slides as separate images, PowerPoint tries to create a folder in the document library to place the images inside. If you create the folder before you try to export, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Burgess's answer brought me to look at the PPT filename. It had a space just before the .pptx extention, which was the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, turned out the filename was too long to be saved to where I wanted it so I renamed the file to a shorter version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with exporting a Powerpoint presentation as images. Shortening the names of upper level directories cured the issue.

Query - why was I able to successfully export the presentation as a pdf - maybe I was right at the boundary of what was acceptable.

That is,
`long_pathname/presentation.pdf` was short enough but,
`long_pathname/presentation/slide1.jpeg` was too long.